# core.mjs:6402 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'benefactorID')

Tags: angular, typescript

Im trying to finalize my put method and im getting an error.

My component :

```
class ShowAccommodationDialogComponent {
acceptAccommodation! : AcceptAccommodation;

constructor(
 @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data : number,
 private refugeeService: RefugeeService,
 private toastr: ToastrService,
 ) {}

confirmAccommodation(){
 this.acceptAccommodation.benefactorID = this.data;
 this.refugeeService.confirmAccommodation(this.acceptAccommodation).subscribe(res =>{
   this.toastr.info("Confirmed!")
})
}
}
```

My AcceptAccommodation interface:

```
export interface AcceptAccommodation{
 benefactorID : number;
}
```

Console at chrome shouts at my "this.acceptAccommodation" is undefined.
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say for sure but usually we pass `data` to dialog component with some structure, like an Object, or Array. You could use optional param `?` and if guards to prevent errors if the data is Optional.

Add logging to your constructor, see what you are passing? Is it really just a number?

```js
 @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data : number,
 private refugeeService: RefugeeService,
 private toastr: ToastrService,
 ){
console.log(this.data)
}
```

A typical way to pass data:

```js
this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ShowAccommodationDialogComponent, {
  width: '330px',
  height: '400px',
  data: {
    number: 123
  }
});
```

Thus to access the data:

```
this.acceptAccommodation.benefactorID = this.data.number;
```

Comment: The OP is not actually instantiating this.acceptAccommodation it seems..?

Comment: `this.acceptAccommodation : AcceptAccommodation` seems to be an object type of `AcceptAccommodation` which is correct. My assumption is that he has nothing on `this.data` to be assigned to `this.acceptAccommodation.benefactorID` thus the Object is never initialised. But he could init the Object with `this.acceptAccommodation = {} as AcceptAccommodation` and then populate properties.